# file_get_html error, not working

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom, scrape

I'm using Simple HTML Dom to try scrape a HTML table.
I follow their instructions and have looked at many other code examples, but the file_get_html just doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

// Simple HTML Dom Parser
include('simple_html_dom.php');

//$worlds = ["Amera", "Antica", "Astera", "Aurera", "Aurora", "Bellona", "Belobra", "Beneva", "Calmera", "Calva", "Calvera", "Candia", "Celesta", "Chrona", "Danera", "Dolera", "Efidia", "Eldera", "Ferobra", "Fidera", "Fortera", "Garnera", "Guardia", "Harmonia", "Honera", "Hydera", "Inferna", "Iona", "Irmada", "Julera", "Justera", "Kenora", "Kronera", "Laudera", "Luminera", "Magera", "Menera", "Morta", "Mortera", "Neptera", "Nerana", "Nika", "Olympa", "Osera", "Pacera", "Premia", "Pythera", "Quilia", "Refugia", "Rowana", "Secura", "Serdebra", "Shivera", "Silvera", "Solera", "Tavara", "Thera", "Umera", "Unitera", "Veludera", "Verlana", "Xantera", "Xylana", "Yanara", "Zanera", "Zeluna"];

//foreach ($worlds as $world) {
  // All HTML from the online list
  $html = file_get_html('https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&world=Antica');

  // Search for the online list table content
  foreach ($html->find('tr[class=Table2]') as $row) {
    $name = $row->find('td', 0)->plaintext;
    $level = $row->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
    $vocation = $row->find('td', 2)->plaintext;

    echo $name . ' | ' . $level . ' | ' . $vocation . '<br>';
  }
//}

?>
```

And I get these errors:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking in D:\xampp\htdocs\simple_html_dom.php on line 76

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to seek to position -1 in the stream in D:\xampp\htdocs\simple_html_dom.php on line 76

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 13
```

What am I doing wrong?
The table I am trying to scrape is the "Players Online" table on:
https://secure.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&world=Antica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$html = str_get_html(file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple_html_dom library problem with the latest versions of PHP.
To correct it, simply change "**`$offset = -1,`**" to "**`$offset = 0,`**" in the parameters of the "**file_get_html**" function in the "**simple_html_dom.php**" file.

Comment: superb, this should be the answer!

Comment: awesome! this should be the correct answer! works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about simpledom but i think you might need to use a more robust library like https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte